# How can I prove that if $a$ and $b$ are integers , and if $a\mid b$ then $b\ge a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> How can I prove that if $a$ and $b$ are integers , and if $a\mid b$ then $b\ge a$

I tried doing this, From $$a\mid b \implies $$ a number $k$ exists ,where $b=ak$ Then I did $$ak>a,$$ removed $a$ from each side and got $$ k>1 $$ which didn't really make sense and didn't show anything. So that's basically all I have got. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is false as stated:  $4$ divides $-8$ but $4 > -8$.

Comment: This is true for *positive* integers however and your proof is closeish. It's a little clunky though.

Comment: Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and the [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume $a$ and $b$ to be **positive** integers, then since $a|b$ so $\dfrac ba$ is an integer greater than or equal to $1$, we have $b\ge a$.

Just put the equality sign also and you are done since $k\ge 1\implies ak=b\ge a $.